# Migration error: 1005 making more than one foreign keys in laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4, database-migration

I am getting this error from Laravel 5.4 SQL i am trying to make many foreign key in my one table product. Please help me. Why is it i am getting this error? i was looking and searching for other codes but their structure of making more than one foreign key is like my migration code.

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `store_db`.`#sql-ca4_1f1` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constrai
  nt is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_product_img_id_foreign` foreign ke
  y (`product_img_id`) references `product_images` (`product_img_id`) on delete cascade)
```

Here is my migration code:
  Migration code for products table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_img_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('feature_img');            
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->double('price',15,2);
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')
        ->references('category_id')->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('product_img_id')
        ->references('product_img_id')->on('product_images')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('categories');
    // Schema::drop('product_images');
    Schema::drop('products');      
}
```

Migration code for product_images table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_img_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('product_img');            
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_images');
    }
```

Migration code for categories table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('category_img');            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: by migrating in php artisan

Comment: The error says its trying to drop categories table, are you sure you're not running `migrate:refresh` or the error is coming from another migration?

Comment: i deleted all tables and again i got new error .. please take a look in my edited post i will edit it

Comment: @TheFallen thanks for your reply. please take a look for my new error

Comment: Can you add the migration for `product_images`? The error says that the foreign key between these two columns is not correct.

Comment: @TheFallen hello sir thanks for your reply. please check my updated post

Comment: Are you creating `product_images` table before `products`? The order of the migrations is important because from the `products` migration you are referencing tables which might have not created yet.